# Open-close string amplitude

Tags: quantum-field-theory, string-theory, scattering, conformal-field-theory, correlation-functions

My question is regarding Polchinski question number 6.12 in which we have to find the amplitude for two open and one close tachyon strings.
I found this solution by Matthew Headrick (["A solution manual for Polchinski's "String Theory""](https://arxiv.org/abs/0812.4408)):

[image]

Why does the calculation is done in the disk $D_2$ (as usually done for open strings) and not on the sphere (as usually done for closed strings)?

Edit:
I think that most of my confusion is that it I don't understand how we can compare open with close states. Don't they have different vacuum state and hence totally different Hilbert space?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The calculation done on the disk because in order to be able to have open states we need that our surface will have a boundary.

On the disk we have the boundary that allow us to represent open strings and we also have the interior (bulk) that allow us to represent close strings.

Regarding the vacuum, they do have the same vacuum states and the difference in the excited states is given by the difference between acting with vertex operator on the boundary vs vertex operator in the interior.